# how to close the division below one anchor tag when we click on second anchor tag and anchor tags are generated dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, show-hide

When I clicked on 1st anchor tag the result is displayed below that but when I click on second anchor tag then the result of second anchor tag is displayed below second tag but the result below 1st anchor tag is not hiding and the result of both are displayed respectively. The anchor tag and division where we are printing results are generated dynamically .

Can anyone help me out of this

Here is my jQuery Code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var st = "1";
        var clLiID = 100;
        var fdevLiID = 300;
        var sdevLiID = 400;
        $('.p').click(function (e) {
            //alert("123");
            //e.preventDefault();
            var bid = 2;
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/afcks/search",
                data: {'b_id': bid},
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    //alert(data);
                    var sta = "";
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    var result = "<ul id='loct' >";
                    $.each(obj, function ()
                    {
                        sta = this['branch_id'];
                        //alert(this['course_name']);
                        if (sta == 2)
                        {
                            result = result + "<li  item-checked='true' item-expanded='true' class='treeLi'><a Class='cours' id='alink' temp_id='" + fdevLiID + "' temp_id1='" + sdevLiID + "' cid='" + this['course_id'] + "' bid='" + this['branch_id'] + "' href='javascript:void(0);'>" + this['course_name'] + "</a></li><div class='" + clLiID + "' id='" + fdevLiID + "'></div><div id='" + sdevLiID + "'></div>";
                            fdevLiID++;
                            sdevLiID++;
                            clLiID++;
                        }
                    });
                    result = result + "</ul>";
                    //alert(result);
                    if (st == "1")
                    {
                        $('#img3').attr("src", "http://localhost/main/img/minus.png");
                        document.getElementById("cour1").innerHTML = result;
                        st = "2";
                    } else
                    {
                        $('#img3').attr("src", "http://localhost/main/img/plus.png");
                        document.getElementById("cour1").innerHTML = "";
                        st = "1";
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var st1 = "1";
    $(document).on('click', '.cours', function () {
        //  $('.cours').removeClass("visited");
        //  $(this).addClass("visited");
        $(".cours").hide();
        var cid = $(this).attr("cid");
        var tempid = $(this).attr("temp_id");
        var tempid1 = $(this).attr("temp_id1");

        var bid = $(this).attr("bid");

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/afcks/search_course",
            data: {'c_id': cid, 'b_id': bid},
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                //alert(data);
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var heading = "";

                var status1 = "";
                var status2 = "";
                //var out="
                //<fieldset><legend>Confirmed Batches</legend>";

                var out = "<br/><p id='conf_p'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspConfirmed Batches</p>";

                //out+="<center><table><tr><td>Confirmed Batches</td></tr></table>;
                out += "<table id='confirm_table'  border='2' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' rules=none >";
                //out+="<tr><td>Confirmed Batches</td></tr>";
                out += "<tr><th width='100' height='40' >&nbsp&nbspBatch Code</th><th width='100' height='45'><center>Start Date</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45'><center>Day</center></th><th width='120' align='center' height='45'><center>Batch time</center></th><th width='150' align='center' height='45'><center>Trainer</center></th><th width='100' align='center' height='45'><center>Frequency</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45' ><center>Fees</center></th><th width='110' align='center' height='45'><center>Duration</center></th>";
                var out1 = "<br/><p id='tent_p'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTentative Batches</p><table id='tentative_table' border=2 cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' rules=none >";
                out1 += "<tr><th width='100' height='40' >&nbsp&nbspBatch Code</th><th width='100' height='45'><center>Start Date</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45'><center>Day</center></th><th width='120' align='center' height='45'><center>Batch time</center></th><th width='150' align='center' height='45'><center>Trainer</center></th><th width='100' align='center' height='45'><center>Frequency</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45' ><center>Fees</center></th><th width='110' align='center' height='45'><center>Duration</center></th>";
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
                {

                    var status = obj[i].batchtype;
                    var b_c = obj[i].batch_code;
                    var b_c = b_c.substring(0, 8);
                    var day = obj[i].frequency;
                    var day = day.substring(4, 9);

                    if (status == '1')
                    {
                        out += "<tr border='2' color='black' backgroundcolor=blue ><td width='100' >&nbsp&nbsp" + b_c +
                                "</td><td width='150' ><center>" + obj[i].new_start_date +
                                "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + day +
                                "</center></td><td width='120' ><center>" + obj[i].timings +
                                "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].faculty_Name +
                                "</center></td><td width='50' ><center>" + obj[i].frequency +
                                "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + obj[i].fees +
                                "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].duration +
                                "</center></td></tr>";
                        status1 = '1';
                    }
                    if (status == '2')
                    {
                        out1 += "<tr border='2' color='black' backgroundcolor=blue ><td width='100' >&nbsp&nbsp" + b_c +
                                "</td><td width='150' ><center>" + obj[i].new_start_date +
                                "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + day +
                                "</center></td><td width='120' ><center>" + obj[i].timings +
                                "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].faculty_Name +
                                "</center></td><td width='50' ><center>" + obj[i].frequency +
                                "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + obj[i].fees +
                                "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].duration +
                                "</center></td></tr>";
                        status2 = '2';
                    }
                }

                out += "<br /></table>";
                out1 += "<br /></table>";

                //alert(out);
                //alert(out1);
                //alert(st);
                if (st1 == "1")
                {
                    if (status1 == '1' && status2 == '2')
                    {
                        document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = out;
                        document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = out1;
                    }
                    if (status1 == '1')
                    {
                        document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = out;
                    }
                    if (status2 == '2')
                    {
                        document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = out1;
                    }
                    st1 = "2";
                } else
                {
                    document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = "";
                    st1 = "1";
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            }
        });
        //});
    });

</script>
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="loc" >    
    <div id="locname"> 
        <ul class="loc" >
            <li>
                <div class="c">
                    <img id='img1'class="c" width="35" height="35" src=".\img\plus.png"/>&nbsp


                    <a href='javascript:void(0);' > Camp
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
    </div>
    <div id="cour">

    </div>
</ul>   

<div id="locname"> 
    <ul class="loct" >
        <li >

            <div class="p" >
                <img id='img3'class="p" width="35" height="35" src=".\img\plus.png"/>&nbsp

                <a href='javascript:void(0);' >Pimpri
                </a>

            </div>
        </li>
</div>
<!--<ul class="loct" >-->
<div div id="cour1" >

</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: just before making the ajax call clear all anchor tag htmls by calling document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = "";

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var st = "1";
    var clLiID = 100;
    var fdevLiID = 300;
    var sdevLiID = 400;
    $('.p').click(function(e) {
        var bid = 2;
        var sta = "";
        var obj = [];
        obj.push({
            "branch_id": 2,
            "course_id": 100,
            "course_name": "course_1"
        });
        obj.push({
            "branch_id": 2,
            "course_id": 101,
            "course_name": "course_2"
        });
        obj.push({
            "branch_id": 1,
            "course_id": 102,
            "course_name": "course_3"
        });

        var result = "<ul id='loct' >";
        $.each(obj, function() {
            sta = this['branch_id'];
            //alert(this['course_name']);
            if (sta == 2) {
                result = result + "<li  item-checked='true' item-expanded='true' class='treeLi'><a Class='cours' id='alink' temp_id='" + fdevLiID + "' temp_id1='" + sdevLiID + "' cid='" + this['course_id'] + "' bid='" + this['branch_id'] + "' href='javascript:void(0);'>" + this['course_name'] + "</a></li><div class='newCls " + clLiID + "' id='" + fdevLiID + "'></div><div class='newCls' id='" + sdevLiID + "'></div>";
                fdevLiID++;
                sdevLiID++;
                clLiID++;
            }
        });
        result = result + "</ul>";
        //alert(result);
        if (st == "1") {
            $('#img3').attr("src", "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-minus-empty-128.png");
            document.getElementById("cour1").innerHTML = result;
            st = "2";
        } else {
            $('#img3').attr("src", "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-minus-empty-128.png");
            document.getElementById("cour1").innerHTML = "";
            st = "1";
        }
    });
});

var st1 = "1";
$(document).on('click', '.cours', function() {
    //  $('.cours').removeClass("visited");
    //  $(this).addClass("visited");
    $(".newCls").html('');
    var cid = $(this).attr("cid");
    var tempid = $(this).attr("temp_id");
    var tempid1 = $(this).attr("temp_id1");

    var bid = $(this).attr("bid");
    $(this).toggleClass('IsOpened');
    var IsShow = $(this).hasClass('IsOpened');
    $('.cours').removeClass('IsOpened');
    if (!IsShow) {
        document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('IsOpened');
    var obj = [];
    obj.push({
        "batchtype": 2,
        "batch_code": "1001",
        "frequency": new Date().toString(),
        "new_start_date": "01-01-2017",
        "timings": "10.00",
        "faculty_Name": "faculty_1",
        "fees": "100",
        "duration": "10"
    });
    obj.push({
        "batchtype": 2,
        "batch_code": "1002",
        "frequency": new Date().toString(),
        "new_start_date": "02-01-2017",
        "timings": "11.00",
        "faculty_Name": "faculty_2",
        "fees": "50",
        "duration": "10"
    });
    obj.push({
        "batchtype": 1,
        "batch_code": "1003",
        "frequency": new Date().toString(),
        "new_start_date": "03-01-2017",
        "timings": "12.00",
        "faculty_Name": "faculty_3",
        "fees": "25",
        "duration": "10"
    });

    var heading = "";

    var status1 = "";
    var status2 = "";
    //var out="
    //<fieldset><legend>Confirmed Batches</legend>";

    var out = "<br/><p id='conf_p'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspConfirmed Batches</p>";

    //out+="<center><table><tr><td>Confirmed Batches</td></tr></table>;
    out += "<table class='confirm_table' id='confirm_table'  border='2' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' rules=none >";
    //out+="<tr><td>Confirmed Batches</td></tr>";
    out += "<tr><th width='100' height='40' >&nbsp&nbspBatch Code</th><th width='100' height='45'><center>Start Date</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45'><center>Day</center></th><th width='120' align='center' height='45'><center>Batch time</center></th><th width='150' align='center' height='45'><center>Trainer</center></th><th width='100' align='center' height='45'><center>Frequency</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45' ><center>Fees</center></th><th width='110' align='center' height='45'><center>Duration</center></th>";
    var out1 = "<br/><p id='tent_p'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTentative Batches</p><table id='tentative_table' border=2 cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' rules=none >";
    out1 += "<tr><th width='100' height='40' >&nbsp&nbspBatch Code</th><th width='100' height='45'><center>Start Date</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45'><center>Day</center></th><th width='120' align='center' height='45'><center>Batch time</center></th><th width='150' align='center' height='45'><center>Trainer</center></th><th width='100' align='center' height='45'><center>Frequency</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45' ><center>Fees</center></th><th width='110' align='center' height='45'><center>Duration</center></th>";
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

        var status = obj[i].batchtype;
        var b_c = obj[i].batch_code;
        var b_c = b_c.substring(0, 8);
        var day = obj[i].frequency;
        var day = day.substring(4, 9);

        if (status == '1') {
            out += "<tr border='2' color='black' backgroundcolor=blue ><td width='100' >&nbsp&nbsp" + b_c +
                "</td><td width='150' ><center>" + obj[i].new_start_date +
                "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + day +
                "</center></td><td width='120' ><center>" + obj[i].timings +
                "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].faculty_Name +
                "</center></td><td width='50' ><center>" + obj[i].frequency +
                "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + obj[i].fees +
                "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].duration +
                "</center></td></tr>";
            status1 = '1';
        }
        if (status == '2') {
            out1 += "<tr border='2' color='black' backgroundcolor=blue ><td width='100' >&nbsp&nbsp" + b_c +
                "</td><td width='150' ><center>" + obj[i].new_start_date +
                "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + day +
                "</center></td><td width='120' ><center>" + obj[i].timings +
                "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].faculty_Name +
                "</center></td><td width='50' ><center>" + obj[i].frequency +
                "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + obj[i].fees +
                "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].duration +
                "</center></td></tr>";
            status2 = '2';
        }
    }

    out += "<br /></table>";
    out1 += "<br /></table>";

    if (status1 == '1' && status2 == '2') {
        document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = out;
        document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = out1;
    }
    if (status1 == '1') {
        document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = out;
    }
    if (status2 == '2') {
        document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = out1;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loc" >    
    <div id="locname"> 
        <ul class="loc" >
            <li>
                <div class="c">
                    <img id='img1'class="c" width="35" height="35" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/plus-icon-black-2.png"/>&nbsp


                    <a href='javascript:void(0);' > Camp
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
    </div>
    <div id="cour">

    </div>
</ul>   

<div id="locname"> 
    <ul class="loct" >
        <li >

            <div class="p" >
                <img id='img3'class="p" width="35" height="35" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/plus-icon-black-2.png"/>&nbsp

                <a href='javascript:void(0);' >Pimpri
                </a>

            </div>
        </li>
</div>
<!--<ul class="loct" >-->
<div div id="cour1" >

</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have just hard coded all ajax calls with rough data.
The changes made are

```
$(this).toggleClass('IsOpened');
var IsShow = $(this).hasClass('IsOpened');
$('.cours').removeClass('IsOpened');
if (!IsShow) {
    document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = "";
    return;
}
$(this).addClass('IsOpened');
```

and removed

```
if (st1 == "1") {}
```

condition and added a css class'newCls' to

```
<div class='newCls " + clLiID + "' id='" + fdevLiID + "'></div><div class='newCls' id='" + sdevLiID + "'></div>
```

The final script with ajax calls:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var st = "1";
    var clLiID = 100;
    var fdevLiID = 300;
    var sdevLiID = 400;
    $('.p').click(function(e) {
        var bid = 2;
        var sta = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/afcks/search",
            data: {'b_id': bid},
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                var result = "<ul id='loct' >";
                $.each(obj, function() {
                    sta = this['branch_id'];
                    //alert(this['course_name']);
                    if (sta == 2) {
                        result = result + "<li  item-checked='true' item-expanded='true' class='treeLi'><a Class='cours' id='alink' temp_id='" + fdevLiID + "' temp_id1='" + sdevLiID + "' cid='" + this['course_id'] + "' bid='" + this['branch_id'] + "' href='javascript:void(0);'>" + this['course_name'] + "</a></li><div class='newCls " + clLiID + "' id='" + fdevLiID + "'></div><div class='newCls' id='" + sdevLiID + "'></div>";
                        fdevLiID++;
                        sdevLiID++;
                        clLiID++;
                    }
                });
                result = result + "</ul>";
                //alert(result);
                if (st == "1") {
                    $('#img3').attr("src", "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-minus-empty-128.png");
                    document.getElementById("cour1").innerHTML = result;
                    st = "2";
                } else {
                    $('#img3').attr("src", "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-minus-empty-128.png");
                    document.getElementById("cour1").innerHTML = "";
                    st = "1";
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

var st1 = "1";
$(document).on('click', '.cours', function() {
    //  $('.cours').removeClass("visited");
    //  $(this).addClass("visited");
    $(".newCls").html('');
    var cid = $(this).attr("cid");
    var tempid = $(this).attr("temp_id");
    var tempid1 = $(this).attr("temp_id1");

    var bid = $(this).attr("bid");
    $(this).toggleClass('IsOpened');
    var IsShow = $(this).hasClass('IsOpened');
    $('.cours').removeClass('IsOpened');
    if (!IsShow) {
        document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('IsOpened');
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/afcks/search_course",
        data: {'c_id': cid, 'b_id': bid},
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            var heading = "";

            var status1 = "";
            var status2 = "";
            //var out="
            //<fieldset><legend>Confirmed Batches</legend>";

            var out = "<br/><p id='conf_p'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspConfirmed Batches</p>";

            //out+="<center><table><tr><td>Confirmed Batches</td></tr></table>;
            out += "<table class='confirm_table' id='confirm_table'  border='2' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' rules=none >";
            //out+="<tr><td>Confirmed Batches</td></tr>";
            out += "<tr><th width='100' height='40' >&nbsp&nbspBatch Code</th><th width='100' height='45'><center>Start Date</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45'><center>Day</center></th><th width='120' align='center' height='45'><center>Batch time</center></th><th width='150' align='center' height='45'><center>Trainer</center></th><th width='100' align='center' height='45'><center>Frequency</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45' ><center>Fees</center></th><th width='110' align='center' height='45'><center>Duration</center></th>";
            var out1 = "<br/><p id='tent_p'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTentative Batches</p><table id='tentative_table' border=2 cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' rules=none >";
            out1 += "<tr><th width='100' height='40' >&nbsp&nbspBatch Code</th><th width='100' height='45'><center>Start Date</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45'><center>Day</center></th><th width='120' align='center' height='45'><center>Batch time</center></th><th width='150' align='center' height='45'><center>Trainer</center></th><th width='100' align='center' height='45'><center>Frequency</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45' ><center>Fees</center></th><th width='110' align='center' height='45'><center>Duration</center></th>";
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                var status = obj[i].batchtype;
                var b_c = obj[i].batch_code;
                var b_c = b_c.substring(0, 8);
                var day = obj[i].frequency;
                var day = day.substring(4, 9);

                if (status == '1') {
                    out += "<tr border='2' color='black' backgroundcolor=blue ><td width='100' >&nbsp&nbsp" + b_c +
                        "</td><td width='150' ><center>" + obj[i].new_start_date +
                        "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + day +
                        "</center></td><td width='120' ><center>" + obj[i].timings +
                        "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].faculty_Name +
                        "</center></td><td width='50' ><center>" + obj[i].frequency +
                        "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + obj[i].fees +
                        "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].duration +
                        "</center></td></tr>";
                    status1 = '1';
                }
                if (status == '2') {
                    out1 += "<tr border='2' color='black' backgroundcolor=blue ><td width='100' >&nbsp&nbsp" + b_c +
                        "</td><td width='150' ><center>" + obj[i].new_start_date +
                        "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + day +
                        "</center></td><td width='120' ><center>" + obj[i].timings +
                        "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].faculty_Name +
                        "</center></td><td width='50' ><center>" + obj[i].frequency +
                        "</center></td><td width='50'  ><center>" + obj[i].fees +
                        "</center></td><td width='100' ><center>" + obj[i].duration +
                        "</center></td></tr>";
                    status2 = '2';
                }
            }

            out += "<br /></table>";
            out1 += "<br /></table>";

            if (status1 == '1' && status2 == '2') {
                document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = out;
                document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = out1;
            }
            if (status1 == '1') {
                document.getElementById(tempid).innerHTML = out;
            }
            if (status2 == '2') {
                document.getElementById(tempid1).innerHTML = out1;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: no its hidding all the courses but i dnt want to hide the courses i just want to hide the result below that and we cant clear the tempid and temp_id1 because it will point the current div of the anchor tag

Comment: Then what about adding a new class name to the div showing the text     <div class='New-Class-Name " + clLiID + "' id='" + fdevLiID + "'></div>    and performing a    $('.New-Class-Name').html('')    at first itself ?

Comment: can we declare two class name in a div?

Comment: i wrote the above code as you told me but no result is displayed not even courses are displaying

Comment: yeah i want this only but m fetching the result from database that time its not working

Comment: I have updated the answer with your ajax call under 'The final script with ajax calls:' section. Since I couldn't access you database calls, Its not possible to test that part. If still this didn't work , Can you please share me you response JSON coming from both ajax calls 'search' & 'search_course (for both courses)' so that I can check with the same.